# Is it possible to show an overlay with CPU temp and freq when not playing?

Tags: cpu-usage, temperature, overlay, cpu-temperature

I actually learned to use RTSS and HWinfo to display an overlay with CPU temp and CPU frequency, but this solution seems to work only when I'm playing.

There is a way or another program that can add an overlay to display me those values (I need only the CPU temp and freq, not FPS or other stuffs) but without the necessity of playing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are free products that are said to do that:

- [**Samurize**](http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/)

[image]

- [**Rainmeter**](https://www.rainmeter.net/)

[image]

- [**MSI Afterburner**](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=161235.0)

Comment: Rainmeter is perfect thank you! I've installed this "skin": https://www.deviantart.com/pul53dr1v3r/art/illustro-Pulsar-2-2-HWiNFO-Rainmeter-789616481